# How long does a Windows machine use its old SAM name after the computer name is changed?

Tags: windows, active-directory, wcf

I changed the name of a domain-joined Windows 10 Pro machine and rebooted it immediately as suggested. When the system came back up, it did have the new name (`\\NEWNAME\share\` works), but WCF clients running as SYSTEM still identified to other machines (that check `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name`) using the old name. I confirmed that all relevant attributes in Active Directory had been updated. This is causing problems because the WCF server expects the SAM name to match the name used in UNC paths.

Other possibly-relevant information:

- There are supposed to be two domain controllers, one running Windows Server 2008 and the other Windows Server 2008 R2 (primary), but only the primary one is up
- The machine in question is 64-bit
- The account that changed the machine name is a member of the Domain Admins group
- The WCF session is configured to allow impersonation, but that feature is not used by the server
- File and folder sharing is enabled on all machines involved, as is the remote management firewall exception

How long will the machine use the old SAM name on the network? How can I force it to use the new one?